# TimeZone issue with Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, timezone

When a date is returned from our UTC server database Windows very helpfully changes the Date to a DateTime (say 23 June 2017 to 2017-06-23 00:00) and then makes an adjustment for the current Time Zone (to, say 2017-06-22 16:00)... For years we have used the code below to convert it back...

About four months ago users running Windows 7 (Windows 10 doesn't seem to be effected) that did not have 'Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time' checked, or live in a state like Arizona where that option is not available, noticed that reports where returning the date from the day before - our DB is returning the correct date but the conversion is no longer working correctly..

Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
Public Function LocalDateFormat(ByVal InputDate As Date) As String
    Dim vDate As String = InputDate.ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim LocalZone As TimeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone
    Dim CurrentOffset As TimeSpan = LocalZone.GetUtcOffset(InputDate)
    Dim DayLightSaving As Boolean = LocalZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(InputDate)
    Dim CalculatedOffset As New DateTime(InputDate.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local)
    If CurrentOffset.CompareTo(TimeSpan.Zero) < 0 Then
        CalculatedOffset -= LocalZone.GetUtcOffset(InputDate)
        If DayLightSaving = True Then
            CalculatedOffset = CalculatedOffset.AddHours(1)
        End If
    Else
        CalculatedOffset += LocalZone.GetUtcOffset(InputDate)
        If DayLightSaving = True Then
            CalculatedOffset = CalculatedOffset.AddHours(-1)
        End If
    End If

    InputDate = CalculatedOffset

    Dim vCulture As String = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString
    Dim vReturnDate As String = ""
    Select Case vCulture
        Case "en-US"
            vReturnDate = Format(InputDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        Case "en-GB"
            vReturnDate = Format(InputDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")
        Case Else
            vReturnDate = Format(InputDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    End Select
    Return vReturnDate

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire function can be re-written as:

```
Public Function LocalDateFormat(ByVal InputDate As Date) As String
    Return InputDate.ToLocalTime().ToShortDateString()
End Function
```

With the code so small, you may want to rethink whether there's any benefit of having this in a function at all.

As far as why your existing function didn't work properly:

- `TimeZone.GetUtcOffset` already factors in whether DST is in effect or not, though it has some problems with that that are described in the MSDN docs.
- You shouldn't be using `TimeZone` any more at all.  If you need to work with time zones, use `TimeZoneInfo`, or [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  In this case, you don't need either of them, as you're just converting from UTC to local time, which is what `DateTime.ToLocalTime` does.
- This code has some logic that appears to think one should *subtract* an hour for DST if the offset is positive.  Sorry, but DST doesn't work that way - you always add an hour (unless you are in Lord Howe Island, Australia, where you add 30 minutes).
- It also seems to think you should add the offset from UTC if its positive and subtract it if its negative.  This is essentially an absolute value function, and also incorrect.
- All the culture stuff is handled for you by formatting within the current culture.  There's no need to do it by hand.

You say it works fine on Windows 10, but I'm sorry - this is bad code that will have errors wherever it is run.  Just use the built-in APIs provided by the framework.  Don't reinvent the wheel. :)

Comment: The strangest thing - updated the function to your code, VS had a fit and wouldn't run because of the zero errors reported. Restarted VS and ran the app in Win 7 - it still reported the incorrect date... Ran the original app in Win 10 and it reported the correct date... About ten minutes later both the updated and original app suddenly reported the correct date with Win 7 - voted up and marked as the answer unless a Ouija board can come up with anything better!

Comment: The existing code was ported over from a WinForms app around 2014 and always returned the correct value until a few months ago when it threw the toys out - something must have changed in a Windows update that broke it for Daylight Savings - but thank you for pointing out a much easier way of doing it :-)

Comment: My guess is that *some* of your values were correct, but many were not.  Perhaps it was never run in other parts of the world.  There were indeed changes in Windows around time zones, but that was with Vista.  Nothing much has changed since then, other than keeping up with the time zone changes themselves.  Anyway, glad you have a good solution now.  Cheers.

Comment: We have workstations set to UTC, no DST, and noticed the issue on Win 7 boxes - checking DST corrected it... Customers in Arizona had the same problem but no option for DST.. Most of these customers have been using our software for over five years and it only surfaced a few months ago after installing updates. Will get an update of our own out this weekend and see if that solves it...

Comment: Sure, but if you had customers in Europe, Asia, or Australia, I'm sure you'd have loads of bug reports by now. ;)

Comment: We do in the UK, which is in Europe, but soon, thankfully, not part of the union, or Common Market as they originally 'packaged' it - another soap box, another time :-) Still nags me that it worked all those years, then just flipped. Curious minds like to ponder this stuff, more so on a Friday evening... Thank you again for your response

Comment: Still the same issue for customers in Arizona using Win 7 - Win 10 still not effected - sigh

Comment: @gchq - I'll be happy to help, but you'll have to be more specific. I was able to respond to the code you presented above, but I still am not sure what you mean by it not working.  If you can present a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please open another question and I'll respond there.  Or feel free to contact me directly (mj1856 at hotmail)

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks for the response - I am trying to gather as much info as possible - just had one report of the same issue in Nevada - I will send you and email shortly